# Polymer 1.0 / leaflet-map 1.0: lat/long not updating on moveend event

Tags: events, listener, coordinates, leaflet, polymer-1.0

I have a map element in a section of an HTML page using Polymer 1.0 and leaflet-map 1.0:

```
         <section data-route="Page">
          <div flex>
              <my-maps id="mymap"  flex></my-maps> 
          </div>
        </section>
```

I am trying to add an event to the element that will pass the lat/long of the center coordinates to the console window anytime the map is panned, similar to the 'event' example given here: [Polymer Leaflet demo](https://leaflet-extras.github.io/leaflet-map/demo.html)

The problem is that the Lat/Long coordinates do not update; I only see the center coordinates of the starting center point.  The map should open initially centered on a geolocated point, with a marker at that point.
I have tried adding the event script to the main index page, and to the element registration as so:

```
 <script>
    Polymer({
     is: "my-maps",
        ready: function () {
      L.Icon.Default.imagePath="../../bower_components/leaflet/dist/images";
     },

     listeners:{
       'moveend': 'testmove'
      },
     testmove: function(e){
        var text = "Center: " + this.latitude.toFixed(9)
                          + ", " + this.longitude.toFixed(9);
        console.log(text); 
      }

 });
 </script>
```

... But I get the same result in both cases; the event fires, but only the initial center point coordinates are passed to the console.

Here is the HTML for my-maps element:

```
<dom-module id="my-maps">
<style>
:host {
    height: 100%;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
leaflet-map {
    position:absolute;
        height: 900px;
        width:100%;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
</style>
<template>
  <leaflet-map latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" zoom="14"> 
    <leaflet-geolocation enable-high-accuracy latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}">
     </leaflet-geolocation>     
        <template is="dom-if" if="{{latitude}}">
        <leaflet-marker latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}">                 
        </leaflet-marker>
        </template>
  </leaflet-map>
</template>

(Polymer registration here)
</dom-module>
```

I tried adding the listener to the leaflet-map tag as well (on-moveend), and I tried moving the registration inside and outside of dom-module element,  but same result.  I added an id to the map and assigned that lat and long to that instance as Ricky suggests, but now the geolocation point moves to the center on each map pan (where it should remain on the geolocated point.)

Comment: Can you share the HTML of your `my-maps` element?

Comment: I added the code above.  This is in a separate html file ('my-maps.html')

Comment: in doing this I (sort of)solved the problem, but uncovered another issue: if I replace the hard-code lat/long with the latitude/longitude data binding property, the center lat/long updates correctly in console.  But now, the center marker moves to the new center as well.  I would like the marker to stay on the geolocated point, but the center of the visible map to be updated on a move event.

Comment: @Mogsdad - please change your edit to the second block of code back to how it was-writing the text comment in the code block makes no sense.

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing it out - 'bot was thrown off by improperly formatted elipses and removed an extra line feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I essentially answered my extended question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045523/how-to-use-map-locate-with-polymer-1-0-leaflet-map-1-0).  My solution involved editing the leaflet-map element itself, by adding a one-time listener for the initial latitude and longitude if given by the geolocator.  If the geolocator fails, the map pans to a default location.  I removed the latitude and longitude property from the leaflet-map element tag in my custom map element.

Answer (score 1):

To make the marker stay on the geo-located point, but update the center co-ords, simply add an `id` to the `leaflet-map` and grab the `latitude` and `longitude` attributes:

```
<leaflet-map id="map">

...

testmove: function(e) {
  var text = 'Center: ' + this.$.map.latitude.toFixed(9)
                       + ', ' + this.$.map.longitude.toFixed(9); 
  console.log(text);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that does seem to work if I hard-code the lat & long for the initial map (with an id added).  But I would like the map to center on the geolocated point, by passing in the latitude and longitude properties.  If I have this, adding the id does not change anything. also, if I also add a leaflet-circle to the inner template (along with the marker), it only renders if I have a hard-coded lat and long in the map element.

Comment: Why don't you just set the map's lat/long imperatively on the `ready` callback instead? (`this.$.map.latitude = '...'`).

Comment: I am not sure how to do that ...how can I pass the property from geolocation into the registration for my-map? I tried to give an id to the geolocation element and pass the property in that way (this.$.locate.latitude, with locate as id) but that didn't work.

Comment: Is the problem because the geolocation element in this case is a child of the map element? he error given = "Cannot read property 'lat' of null'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve now. If I've answered your original question it may be wiser to create a new question or update your original question with more clarity. Cheers.

Comment: I modified my question, to say that the map should open initially on a geolocated point.  I don't understand how to 'set the map's lat/long imperatively' as you suggest.  I have tried several variations of assigning the map's lat long to the lat long attribute of 'locate' (leaflet-geolocation) in the 'ready' function of my-map's registration, but none have worked.  What should be the geolocated point moves to the center of the map on each map pan.  IF you modify your answer with this info I will makr it as answered. Thanks for your help.

Comment: ..I looked into the idea of setting the property imperatively as you suggest @Ricky ... I came across this on Github; apparently data binding using Javascript is not available in Polymer 1.0..this is what you were suggesting right? https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/1796

Comment: By imperative, I simply meant set the lat/long value programatically? `this.$.map.latitude = 12.1523` ... However, I'm unclear what behaviour you're looking for ... On load the map has a marker on a geo-located point and then when you pan it stays on that point, but then you capture the centre of the map?

Comment: Yes, the initial map needs to center on the current geolocation, so a hard-coded value will not work.  The geolocated point should not change if the map's center changes on a pan or zoom.