# Polymer 1.0 / leaflet-map: how to implement Leaflet functions to web components

Tags: zooming, leaflet, latitude-longitude, polymer-1.0, web-component

This question is an extension of [a previous question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045523/how-to-use-map-locate-with-polymer-1-0-leaflet-map-1-0). 
I am new to both Polymer 1.0 and the leaflet-map web component, and so far I am unable to use any of Leaflet functionality I have used with ease in Javascript / HTML / CSS based Leaflet web apps.

For example, I would like to set the map view to center on a click on the map.  I tried some variations of this idea, based on some examples I found on SO:

map element in html:

```
<leaflet-map id="thismap"  latitude="{{latitude}}" longitude="{{longitude}}" zoom="14"  >
```

map element registration:

```
<script>
 Polymer({
  is: "my-maps",
  ready: function () {
       L.Icon.Default.imagePath="../../bower_components/leaflet/dist/images";      

   },
    attached: function(){
      this.map = L.map(thismap);
   },
  listeners:{
   'tap': 'testmove'
   },
  testmove: function(e){
    console.log("tapped");      
    this.map.setView([40.675951373, -73.989100456], 14);
     console.log("map center: "+this.map.getCenter());
  }
});
</script>
```

In this case, 'getCenter' outputs the center point as assigned in 'setView', but the visible map does not pan to center on this point, as I would hope.

I can't find any examples in the leaflet-map documentation or anywhere else that show any type of dynamic functionality of this sort (map resizing on a click, button press etc).
Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key I found is to write any method that is dependent on  Leaflet source functions within the leaflet-map core element (leaflet-core.html).

(in leaflet-core.html)

```
Polymer({
    is: 'leaflet-map',

 ...

 map.on('click', function(e) {                      
            this.map.setView([e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng], this.map.zoom);
        }, this);

....

});
```

One issue is that 'tap' is not one of the events defined in leaflet-core.html, so I had to use 'click'.  But this sufficed for this test purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Leaflet, but for this specific issue your problem may be a typo in the `attached` method:

`thismap = L.map(this, {`

should be

`this.map = L.map(this, {`

That way the `map` property on `this` is set to whatever `L.map` returns. Then in `testmove` `this.map` should be set.

Comment: @Taylpor sorry that was a typo, I fixed that and added the html element of the map for some clarity.  I also removed the center and zoom properties from the map constructor; they are set in the map element tag as bound properties.  In this case I do not get any error, but i also do not get any response from 'setVIew' which should reset the map extent to center on that point.  I added a 'getCenter function above; see the additional comments in my question .

Comment: ps--I also tried to assign the leaflet map constructor to this.$.map, and use that for the map functions, with the same result...it is as if this.map (or this.$.map) is a different instance of the map than 'thismap', the ID of the map element.